# need only key(Status) and value(0) from json in swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift3, xcode8, ios10

```
{
"items": [
{
"startTime": "1498667581661",
"endTime": "1498667821661",
"dateTime": "2017-06-28T16:33:01.661Z",
"totalTime": "4",
"auctionName": "Bbbb",
"status": 1,
"id": "4760417733705728",
"kind": "auctionTimeApi#resourcesItem"
},
{
"startTime": "1498772812087",
"endTime": "1498772992087",
"dateTime": "2017-06-29T21:46:52.087Z",
"totalTime": "3",
"auctionName": "sdasdasdd",
"status": 1,
"id": "5080491044634624",
"kind": "auctionTimeApi#resourcesItem"
},
{
"startTime": "1498833895423",
"endTime": "1498834375423",
"dateTime": "2017-06-30T14:44:55.423Z",
"totalTime": "8",
"auctionName": "Boston",
"status": 1,
"id": "5085211482128384",
"kind": "auctionTimeApi#resourcesItem"
},
{
"startTime": "1498767894987",
"endTime": "1498768254987",
"dateTime": "2017-06-29T20:24:54.987Z",
"totalTime": "6",
"auctionName": "Dfddd",
"status": 0,
"id": "5111065843073024",
"kind": "auctionTimeApi#resourcesItem"
},
{
"startTime": "1498640043323",
"endTime": "1498640283323",
"dateTime": "2017-06-28T08:54:03.323Z",
"totalTime": "4",
"auctionName": "Andsda",
"status": 1,
"id": "5118511437316096",
"kind": "auctionTimeApi#resourcesItem"
},
{
"startTime": "1498807228606",
"endTime": "1498807348606",
"dateTime": "2017-06-30T07:20:28.606Z",
"totalTime": "2",
"auctionName": "Dxf",
"status": 1,
"id": "5146118144917504",
"kind": "auctionTimeApi#resourcesItem"
},
{
"startTime": "1498806518484",
"endTime": "1498807358484",
"dateTime": "2017-06-30T07:08:38.484Z",
"totalTime": "14",
"auctionName": "rrrtttt",
"status": 1,
"id": "5151952589553664",
"kind": "auctionTimeApi#resourcesItem"
},
{
"startTime": "1498807683483",
"endTime": "1498807863483",
"dateTime": "2017-06-30T07:28:03.483Z",
"totalTime": "3",
"auctionName": "wwew",
"status": 1,
"id": "5956451503702016",
"kind": "auctionTimeApi#resourcesItem"
},
{
"startTime": "1498803576630",
"endTime": "1498803816630",
"dateTime": "2017-06-30T06:19:36.630Z",
"totalTime": "4",
"auctionName": "zzzz",
"status": 0,
"id": "5964732200648704",
"kind": "auctionTimeApi#resourcesItem"
},
{
"startTime": "1498833083854",
"endTime": "1498833563854",
"dateTime": "2017-06-30T14:31:23.854Z",
"totalTime": "8",
"auctionName": "Dartmouth",
"status": 0,
"id": "6314781967384576",
"kind": "auctionTimeApi#resourcesItem"
}
],
"kind": "auctionTimeApi#resources",
"etag": "\"l-71RhD3VMYkQ-s_W643oBlpkCw/1SZlmWzcSB8XxEnhJpjVvwPV5k4\""
}
```

Above is my JSON data in the Google cloud 
Add This is my SWIFT3 code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource {



    @IBOutlet weak var auctionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var auctionTableView: UITableView!


    var fetchAuctionName = [AuctionName]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        auctionTableView.dataSource = self

        parseData()
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return fetchAuctionName.count

    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = auctionTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        cell?.textLabel?.text = fetchAuctionName[indexPath.row].auctionname
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = fetchAuctionName[indexPath.row].auctionname

        return cell!
    }



    func parseData() {

        fetchAuctionName = []

        let url = "urll"
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if (error != nil){
                print("Error")
            }
            else{


                do{
                    let fetchData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                    let jsonArray = fetchData.value(forKey: "items") as! NSArray


                    for eachFetchedAuctionName in jsonArray {

                        let eachAuctionName = eachFetchedAuctionName as! [String : Any]

                        let auctionname = eachAuctionName["auctionName"] as! String

                        self.fetchAuctionName.append(AuctionName(auctionname: auctionname));

                    }



                    self.auctionTableView.reloadData()



                }
                catch{
                    print("Error 2")
                }
            }

        }
        task.resume()

    }

}


class AuctionName: NSObject {

    var auctionname : String

    init(auctionname : String) {
        self.auctionname = auctionname

    }
}
```

With this code I can print all the status values from the JSON data

My question is; I just need those with a status value of 0 to be printed. How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Comment: use nspredicate .

Comment: thank you for your time ..  bt i think we don't need nspredicate in this . just if statement is enough that it. any ways thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
     func parseData() {

            fetchAuctionName = []

            let url = "urlllll"
            var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"

            let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

                if (error != nil){
                    print("Error")
                }
                else{

                       do{
                        let fetchData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                        let jsonArray = fetchData.value(forKey: "items") as! NSArray


                        for eachFetchedAuctionName in jsonArray {

                       let eachAuctionName = eachFetchedAuctionName as! [String : Any]

              let auctionname = eachAuctionName["auctionName"] as! String
               if let status = eachAuctionName["staus"] as? Bool{
                if status == true{
                   self.fetchAuctionName.append(AuctionName(auctionname: auctionname));
                }

             }                    
    }
                    self.auctionTableView.reloadData()
                }
                catch{
                    print("Error 2")
                }
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay..  but the i solved it with this code and its working.        if(eachAuctionName["status"] as! Int == 0)
                        {
                            self.fetchAuctionName.append(AuctionName(auctionname: auctionname));
                        }

Answer (score 0):

```
        for eachFetchedAuctionName in jsonArray {

         let eachAuctionName = eachFetchedAuctionName as! [String : Any]
         let auctionname = eachAuctionName["auctionName"] as! String
        self.fetchAuctionName.append(AuctionName(auctionname: auctionname));

    // you can typecast to either String or an Int and then compare it respectively 
   //with a String "1" or an Int(1), whichever suits your app


        guard let status = eachAuctionName["status"] as! Int else { return }
            if status == 0 {
                print("0 found")
              }
        }
```

One suggestion: use swift 4 Decodable protocol, to parse JSON easily into custom objects either a struct or a class of your choice, makes the code looks nice and clean.

Comment: initializer for conditional binding must have optional type not 'string'  I got this error!!!!

Comment: Thank you for your replay..  but the i solved it with this code and its working.        if(eachAuctionName["status"] as! Int == 0)
                        {
                            self.fetchAuctionName.append(AuctionName(auctionname: auctionname));
                        }

Comment: Yeah, as I said, it depends on your app how to parse it, whether as String or Int, I'll update my answer, please it accept it.